# Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular

I am getting below  error on types of Events. ERROR:Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

my `.ts` file,

```
select4File(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

        reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
            this.imageurl2 = event.target.result;


        }
        this.selectedfiles = event.target.files;
    }

}
```

```
my html,
 <div class="form-inline" Style="color: black">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <label style ="color: black">Additional ID Back</label>
            <form >
          <div class="form-inline" >
              <img [src]="imageurl2" height="200"> <br/>
            <input type="file"(change)="select4File($event)"  />
          </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <button (click)="uploadADIDback()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:0 35%;position:relative;left:-35px;background-color: #3560a5;  /* blue */">Upload</button>
          </div>
          </div>
```

help here to solve this error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  reader.onload = () => {
    // called once readAsDataURL is completed
    this.imageurl2 = reader.result;
  };
```

Comment: it"s working...but in my .ts am using nearly 5-6 selectFile(event).. when i tired to change all as(reader.result) it still showing me the error...help here @nitin

Comment: @Leo_Roy Is selectFile(event) a common function? Right?

Answer (score 1):

Worked like a charm

```
change(event) {
var file = event.target.files[0];
if (!file) return;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = (event) => {
  this.url = reader.result;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already getting an `event` variable from the parent function. rename the onload callback event variable

```
 reader.onload = (e) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      this.imageurl2 = e.target.result; 
 }
```

Comment: What is the error and show where u call the `select4File` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type you want to specify for the event: `ProgressEvent<FileReader>`

```
select4File(event) {
  // ...
  reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
    this.imageurl2 = event.target.result;
  }
  // ...
}
```

This way, you should be able to get TS to not throw the error, and also find `result` as property on `target` with the TS intellisense.